# confused about xor usage in x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, xor

I get that `xor` is exclusive or and can be used for 
`xorl %ebx %ebx` can be used to clear the register

however while reading I came across a different usage of `xorl` and am confused.
`xorl 12(%ebp),%eax` which meant `eax = x^y`

in this context its used for the exponentiation of x. Is this incorrect usage? Thanks.

Comment: The `^` symbol is often used to indicate an XOR operation. In fact, it is used as the XOR operator in many programming languages, including C, Perl and Python.

Comment: ah, yeah i got confused. I immediately thought of power operation but i guess it was used in the exclusive or context. thanks.

Comment: In this context, `^` is the C operator for exclusive or. So `x^y` means `x xor y` and not `x to the power of y`. So it is not the exponentiation operator.

Answer (score 4):

Here `^` means XOR, as is used in C.

Assuming we are using AT&T notation, then

```
xorl 12(%ebp), %eax
```

will `xor` `eax` with the value 12 bytes from `ebp` (if I remember my assembler right), which would normally be a local variable. So, it would be more correct to say

```
eax ^= y
```

(assuming `y` is at `ebp+12`), or

```
x ^= y
```

if `x` is stored in the `eax` register.

Comment: Intel notation? Looks like AT&T syntax to me.

Comment: @nrz doh - that's what I meant, but I then wrote the wrong thing. Thanks - fixed.